# How to configure/track data with dvc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, dvc, cml

I'm tying out DVC (https://dvc.org/) , based on the docs provided , i followed the sample, with following commands (see below) . I created a folder called storage and ran => dvc add storage.

now if i started adding data or csv , for example somefile.csv to this folder, do i need to run dvc add storage/somefile.csv ?

and i eventually want to run this on aws , so once is setup a s3 bucket , push my data to the bucket and run my training job on aws. I'm looking at CML (cml.dev) as well, which looks like , let me do that . will CML configuration know to pull from my remote storage?

also , i'm not too familiar with CML yet , is this for just running jobs?

i've tried set up with following commands

```
- git init
- dvc init

- mkdir storage 

#added a storage folder for data then 
- dvc add storage

- git commit

#set up the remote storage
- dvc remote add remote_storage s3://somebucket

- dvc push
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some high-level answers for your high-level questions.

DVC is designed to behave in a very similar way to git, if you are ever in dought you should run `dvc status`

In your example, if you add a file to `./storage` then [`dvc status`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/status) will show that it has been modified, you can run `dvc commit` which will update your tracking file `storage.dvc` which should be then committed with git. I would run [`dvc install`](https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/install) to set up some pre-commit hooks which will help do this automatically for you.

Your `.dvc/config` should contain the bucket name and config options. So CML or anyone machine can run `dvc pull` to get the data so long as they have credentials.

On CML I would think of it as a collection of tools to help you interact with GitLab/GitHub you can follow one of the examples at https://cml.dev. It sounds like you are looking at the `cml runner launch` command (using GitHub as an example) can provision an ec2 instance for you and installs the GitHub Actions agent to run subsequent CI/CD jobs.

Comment: I appreciat it. I did install dvc. based on your comments, so once do => dvc add data/somefile.csv , i will have to run -> dvc commit and then git commit? what about pulling data then , i do a git pull , then a dvc pull , right? i apologize for basic question.

Comment: The initial add essentially performs the `dvc commit` so you don't need to do a `dvc commit` unless you change something in that dir.

The tracking files are versioned via git, so only normal git commands are needed to interact with them. Running `dvc pull` will retrieve the files referenced in the `.dvc` tracking files.